# XML namespaces for Primefaces 4.0

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.
Component stack: JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 4.0, Tomcat 7.

Creating simple xhtml with code:

```
<ui:composition template="rootTemplate.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
</ui:composition>
```

But IDEA can't fetch primefaces url and highlights it with red.

Browser shows 404 error when trying to load http://primefaces.org/ui as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import the primefaces jar file ?  And is it executing despite the warning ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan, yes I use maven dependency org.primefaces.primefaces:4.0 and the application executes well - I see all Primefaces components. But in IDEA I can't use IDE's help as autocomplete and others as IDEA can't download xml namespace definition. http://primefaces.org/ui gives 404 error. Can you load http://primefaces.org/ui ? Or you get 404 error as well?

Comment: _primefaces.org/ui gives 404 error_ Me too, and it's normal. Your problem is IDE specific.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan, I didn't found the source of the problem. But changing JSF implementation from com.sun.faces:2.2.5 to com.sun.faces:2.2.6 fixed the problem. Now IDEA founds the required *.taglib.xml file in primefaces-4.0.jar. When changing back to 2.2.5 version the problem returns :( What a mystic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found the source of the problem.

But changing JSF implementation from com.sun.faces:2.2.5 to com.sun.faces:2.2.6 fixed the problem.

Now IDEA founds the required *.taglib.xml file in primefaces-4.0.jar.

When changing back to 2.2.5 version the problem returns :(

What a mystic?

===== UPDATE =====

In IDEA one can set up the taglib manually. It's placed in primefaces-4.0.jar/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml

Answer (score 3):

1) please be sure to add framework support

[image]
[image]

2) IDEA sometimes need to be synchronized. therefore use "Reimport All Maven Projects" button.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, @bhdrk, but all this was done many thimes. I found the solution and wrote it in an answer.

Comment: If the Primefaces doesn't show up under `Add Framework Support` make sure in Settings > Plugins that `Java EE: Java Server Faces` is enabled.